# Will this program cause memory leaks?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, memory-leaks, heap-memory, async.js

I can't seem to figure out what causes memory leak here. I'm getting the "heap out of memory" error. I tried to set all variables that have no use to `null` but it didn't work. I tried using a simple `forEach` function instead of using the `each` function from `async.js` but that also didn't work. When looking at the ram usage of the app in task manager, the longer it runs, the higher the ram it consumes. But I can't seem to figure out what's not being cleaned or garbage collected.

```
const fs = require('fs')

const mj = require('mathjax-node-sre')
const each = require('async/each')
const colors = require('colors')
const cliProgress = require('cli-progress')
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom')

mj.config({ displayErrors: false })

console.log('')

const progressBar = new cliProgress.SingleBar({
  format: '  MathML to SRE  ' + colors.cyan('{bar}') + '  {percentage}%  |  {value}/{total} Files',
  barCompleteChar: '\u2588',
  barIncompleteChar: '\u2591',
  hideCursor: true
})

let files = fs.readdirSync('C:/Users/koliva/Desktop/xml2/').filter(file => file.endsWith('\.xml') && !file.endsWith('_sre\.xml'))
let mjErrors = []

progressBar.start(files.length, 0)

each(files, (mml, callback) => {
  try {
    let inputFileName = mml
    let outpuFileName = 'C:/Users/koliva/Desktop/xml2/' + mml.replace('\.xml', '_sre.xml')

    mml = fs.readFileSync('C:/Users/koliva/Desktop/xml2/' + mml, 'utf8')

    mj.typeset({ math: mml, format: 'MathML', svg: true }, data => {
      let sre = new JSDOM(data.svg).window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML

      mml = new JSDOM(mml)
      mml.window.document.getElementsByTagName('mml:math')[0].setAttribute('alttext', sre)

      fs.writeFileSync(outpuFileName, mml.serialize().replace(/<\/?body>|<\/?html>|<\/?head>/g, ''))
      progressBar.increment()
      if (data.errors) {
        mjErrors = mjErrors.concat({ 'name': inputFileName, 'errors': data.errors })
      }
      callback()
    })
  } catch (error) {
    callback(error)
  }
}, (err) => {
     // do something
})
```

Comment: Why read/writeFileSync? Have you tried async call to FS? How many times is the each being repeated? Eg how many files are in the directory?

Comment: How many files are you processing?  If `ml.typeset()` is asynchronous, then you're running ALL the files in parallel and thus they are all in memory at once, along with their JSDOM.  Perhaps you need to run them one at a time or N at a time, not all at once.

Comment: @Isolated The behavior is kinda weird. I have two folders. Folder 1 contains 3.6k files. Folder 2 contais 2.4k files. I dont get any errors on folder 1, but the error occurs on folder 2.

Comment: @youhavenomana I think jfriend00 made a good point, especially with that many files. You make two synchronous requests to the file system, my math is awful but 3.6k + 2.4k = 6kx2 = 12000 FS operations (synchronous). Which is probably the worst thing you can do to the event-loop and memory. I'd recommend finding out why the async methods didn't work, instead of resorting to synchronous functions.